# Can Find One Child in Unity but Not the Other

Tags: unity-game-engine, if-statement, parent-child

I'm trying to find two different children and update them when certain parameters are met as demonstrated in the code below.

```
private void UpdateHpBar()
    {
        if (GetComponentInChildren<Image>() != null && GetComponentInChildren<Image>().name == "HealthBar")
        {
            GetComponentInChildren<Image>().transform.localScale = new Vector3((float)((float)HitPoints / (float)TotalHitPoints), 1, 1);
            GetComponentInChildren<Image>().color = Color.Lerp(Color.red, Color.green,
                (float)((float)HitPoints / (float)TotalHitPoints));
        }
    }

    public void UpdateSupBar()
    {
        if (GetComponentInChildren<Image>() != null && GetComponentInChildren<Image>().name == "SuppressionBar")
        {

            GetComponentInChildren<Image>().transform.localScale = new Vector3((float)((float)SuppressPoints / (float)TotalSuppressPoints), 1, 1);

        }
    }
```

The problem is that the first one UpdateHpBar() works fine but the second one UpdateSupBar() doesn't and I can't find the problem. I've checked the usual problems such as the name being wrong or the child not actually being a child but those aren't the issue. When I run the debugger, it gets to the if-statement fine but then never goes inside, so it must be failing the if-statement.  The suppress points are also changing and making a fraction. They're just not showing up on the suppression bar.

I also tried using `transform.Find("SuppressionBar")` 
and 
`GetComponentInChildren<Image>().CompareTag("Suppress")`
but neither of those worked.

I just don't get why the first one works but the second one doesn't.

Comment: Because  getcomponentinchildren returns 1 item it will always return the same one

Comment: So it will only ever return the first one? How would I get to the second child?

Comment: Well you could “getcomponentsinchildren” or you could find the object by name and get the image off it or as shown below drag the bars in and set them in the inspector. 

Ps good rule of thumb. If you have to get/search for anything more than once. Store it and reuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetComponentInChildren returns the first component of the type you specifie so if it finds the HpBar's Image component first its always going to be te case.

An easy unity way to make your code work better is simply adding a hard reference to each.

```
 [SerializeField] private Image healtBar;
[SerializeField] private Image SuppresionBar;
private void UpdateHpBar()
{

    healtBar.transform.localScale = new Vector3((float)((float)HitPoints / (float)TotalHitPoints), 1, 1);
    healtBar.color = Color.Lerp(Color.red, Color.green,
            (float)((float)HitPoints / (float)TotalHitPoints));

}

public void UpdateSupBar()
{
    SuppresionBar.transform.localScale = new Vector3((float)((float)SuppressPoints / (float)TotalSuppressPoints), 1, 1);        
}
```

the serializefields declared above will show up inside unity on your script. When not in play mode, drag and drop your hpbar and suppression bar onto the fields to link them.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works beautifully now. I'll keep in mind about the serializefield too.